# How to fill missing values by using different conditions

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say that we have the following dataframe. I want to fill the null values of the column height group by column Subject and the following conditions.

1. If there is one missing value in a Subject fills the missing value of this Subject with the other value.
2. If there are two missing values in a Subject, then fill these missing values by using the median height of all subjects that x == 'AA'

Note: In the desired dataframe we must have the same value per Subject.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Subject': [1,1,2,2,3,3], 'x':['AA','AA','BB','BB','AA','AA'], 'height': [130, np.nan, np.nan, 170, np.nan, np.nan]})
```

[image]

Here is the desired dataframe.

[image]

Comment: Could you provide your desired output?

Comment: I have uploaded the desired output!

Comment: but the median of the whole column is 150, and not 130? So why are you saying that the last 2 rows should be filled with 130?

Comment: @sophocles In the second condition of the OP, it says that the median should be taken over the values of the x values that equal the ones missing not over the whole dataset. I believe that if you change your second line of code to this one you should get what the OP wants `df.apply(lambda x: x['height'] if x['height'] == np.nan else df[df['x'] == x['x']]['height'].median() , axis=1)`.

Comment: Thank you xicocaio, that saved me the trouble :)

Comment: thank you both for your help!

Answer (score 5):

You can first `fillna()` using a grouped `ffill()` and `bfill()`, and then using the column `median`:

```
df.groupby('Subject')['height'].fillna(method='ffill',inplace=True).fillna(method='bfill',inplace=True)
df['height'].fillna(df['height'].median(),inplace=True)
```

**Output**:

```
   Subject   x  height
0        1  AA   130.0
1        1  AA   130.0
2        2  BB   170.0
3        2  BB   170.0
4        3  AA   150.0
5        3  AA   150.0
```

**Edit**: If you require that the median should be taken over the values of the x values that equal the ones missing, not over the whole dataset, you could use @xicoaio's advice and replace my second line `df['height'].fillna(df['height'].median(),inplace=True)`, with:

```
df['height'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['height'] if x['height'] == np.nan else df[df['x'] == x['x']]['height'].median() , axis=1)
```

**Output**:

```
   Subject   x  height
0        1  AA   130.0
1        1  AA   130.0
2        2  BB   170.0
3        2  BB   170.0
4        3  AA   130.0
5        3  AA   130.0
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do this in two steps.

First fill in the cases for each `Subject` that has one `height` value

```
df['height_v2'] = np.select([df['height'].isna()], 
                            [df.groupby(['Subject', 'x'])['height'].transform('max')], 
                            default=df['height'])
```

And then fill in the cases where both height values are missing.
Here i am assuming that if a `Subject` has `x=='BB'` we will fill it out based on the median of the `BB` cases.

```
df['height_final'] = df.groupby('x')['height_v2'].transform(np.median)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import groupby, product
import itertools
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame as df


df = pd.DataFrame({'Subject': [1,1,2,2,3,3], 'x':['AA','AA','BB','BB','AA','AA'], 
                   'height': [130, np.nan, np.nan, 170, np.nan, np.nan]})


print(df)
"""
   Subject   x  height
0        1  AA   130.0
1        1  AA     NaN
2        2  BB     NaN
3        2  BB   170.0
4        3  AA     NaN
5        3  AA     NaN
"""

df['height'] = df.groupby('x')['height'].transform('first')
print(df)

"""
   Subject   x  height
0        1  AA   130.0
1        1  AA   130.0
2        2  BB   170.0
3        2  BB   170.0
4        3  AA   130.0
5        3  AA   130.0
"""
```